# Silverlight Value does not fall within expected range when trying to open a xaml

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, xaml

I receive the following message in a simple message pop up, when trying to open the designer of some of my xaml files:

"Value does not fall within expected range"

I've tried to create a new windows and open the xaml files in notepad and copy them in the new one, but even with a new control it gives me this error without even having modifying it.

Here's one of the xamls that gives me an error:

```
<controls:ChildWindow x:Class="Playground.Views.MessageWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
       Width="343" Height="159" 
       Title="MessageWindow" xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="2">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="316*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="216*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="32" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="OKButton" Content="OK" Click="OKButton_Click" Width="75" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,9,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    <dxe:TextEdit HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Name="txtMessage"  IsReadOnly="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Background="#FFE7E9EC" />
</Grid>
```

And here's one that doesn't have this problem:

```
<controls:ChildWindow x:Class="Playground.Views.LogIn"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
       Width="270" Height="200" 
       Title="Log In" xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk" xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="2">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button x:Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel" Click="CancelButton_Click" Width="75" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,12,0,0" Grid.Row="1" />
    <Button x:Name="OKButton" Content="Log In" Click="OKButton_Click" Width="75" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,12,79,0" Grid.Row="1" />
    <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,23,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" Content="Username" />
    <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,56,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" Content="Password" />
    <dxe:CheckEdit HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,85,0,0" Name="checkEdit1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Content="Use CIL/CIP" IsThreeState="False" Checked="checkEdit1_Checked" Unchecked="checkEdit1_Unchecked"/>
    <dxe:CheckEdit Margin="116,85,0,0" Name="remUNCE" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Save Username" IsThreeState="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="120" Checked="remUNCE_Checked" Unchecked="remUNCE_Unchecked"/>
    <dxe:TextEdit HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="86,23,0,0" Name="textEdit1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136" Text="administrator"  />
    <dxe:PasswordBoxEdit HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="86,56,0,0" Name="passwordBoxEdit1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136" />
</Grid>
```

I tried searching for this problem on the internet but all i got were results for duplicate names in the same xaml, which is not the case here, also i'm not injecting any controls in codebehind so there shouldn't be any problem regarding duplicate names.
i use visual studio 2010 and also in case it has any relevance i have devexpress installed, but when i started getting this error i had an earlier version so i upgraded it to the latest in hopes of fixing it, but no luck.

Comment: Just a guess, think it could be the height or width of the column and row definitions - 316*

Comment: I don't have the DevExpress controls, so I took your first XAML file, commented out the `<dxe:TextEdit>` element and didn't encounter any errors.  Do you get any errors if you comment out this element?  If not, it would seem that the problem would be with the DevExpress control, in which case you would be best getting support from DevExpress.

Comment: Nope, no luck, still the same, it happens even if i make a new XAML file, without any DevExpress controls in it, i still receive this error, while on some of the already existing XAML files with DevExpress controls in it,like the one above, it works. Would reinstalling Visual studio help?